# Symfony3 : Generate crud doesn't work

Tags: generator, symfony

I'm trying to use the generate crud feature with my new symfony3 project. I have created a bundle named AdminBundle with the generator, the entity test, also with the generator, all processed well to the end. I checked my file under, i have my class Test.php generated under my src/AdminBundle/Entity/Test.php folder. All is working well.

But when i try to generate a crud following the doc for my test entity with the following command :

```
bin/console generate:doctrine:crud
The Entity shortcut name: AdminBundle:Test
```

I get the following error :

> [RuntimeException]
>     Entity "Test" does not exist in the "AdminBundle" bundle. You may have mistyped the bundle name or maybe the entity doesn't exist yet (create it first with the "doctrine:generate:entity" comm
>     and).

As i said, i already generated the entity with the "doctrine:generate:entity" command, and i type the same name ( AdminBundle:Test ) as i type in my crud generator.

Any ideas ?

Comment: make sure your class name is properly typed, with a capital first letter. and that the namespace is correct.

Comment: Already checked, and yes, both are correct (anyway, it was generated by the entity:generator so i'm sure it's correct ;D)

Comment: the generator has had problems in the past misnaming things and getting namespaces wrong.

Comment: my namespace is namespace AdminBundle\Entity; and my class name : class Test{ ...

Comment: Does the autocomplete popup when you start to type "Admin..." and then autosuggest your class?

Comment: If there are no syntax errors, remember to check if the database server is running.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with sf2.8.

What I did to solve this problem was:

first: generate the form for the entity.
php app/console doctrine:generate:form NameBundle:EntityName

Second: generate the CRUD for Entity
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. One of my entity's attributes annotations were mistyped, causing this error. Check your attributes annotations.

Comment: I generated Entity with console

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` for it to acknowledge the entity as I had the class but the entity was not in the DB yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old issue. But I face it too, just now. I solved it by pointing the class with whole name space.

```
$test = new \AppBundle\Entity\Test();
```