# CRUD command line failing

Tags: symfony

I am  familiarising myself with Symfony3, and getting failure running the CRUD generator. My terminal output below:

```html
➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity

                                             
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator  
                                             


This command helps you generate Doctrine2 entities.

First, you need to give the entity name you want to generate.
You must use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post.

The Entity shortcut name: keys:passcodes
Bundle "keys" does not exist.
The Entity shortcut name: 
➜  keys php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=keys/Passcodes 

                                            
  Welcome to the Symfony bundle generator!  
                                            

Are you planning on sharing this bundle across multiple applications? [no]: 

Your application code must be written in bundles. This command helps
you generate them easily.

Give your bundle a descriptive name, like BlogBundle.
Bundle name [keys/Passcodes]: 
 The namespace must end with Bundle. 
Bundle name [keys/Passcodes]: PasscodeBundle

Bundles are usually generated into the src/ directory. Unless you're
doing something custom, hit enter to keep this default!

Target Directory [src/]: 

What format do you want to use for your generated configuration?

Configuration format (annotation, yml, xml, php) [annotation]: php

                     
  Bundle generation  
                     

> Generating a sample bundle skeleton into app/../src/PasscodeBundle
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/PasscodeBundle.php
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Controller/
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
  created ./app/../tests/PasscodeBundle/Controller/
  created ./app/../tests/PasscodeBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/views/Default/
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/services.php
  created ./app/../src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/routing.php
> Checking that the bundle is autoloaded
> Enabling the bundle inside app/AppKernel.php
  updated ./app/AppKernel.php
> Importing the bundle's routes from the app/config/routing.yml file
  updated ./app/config/routing.yml
> Importing the bundle's services.php from the app/config/config.yml file
  updated ./app/config/config.yml

                                         
  Everything is OK! Now get to work :).  
                                         

➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity                  

                                             
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 entity generator  
                                             


This command helps you generate Doctrine2 entities.

First, you need to give the entity name you want to generate.
You must use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post.

The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle
 The entity name isn't valid ("PasscodeBundle" given, expecting something like AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post) 
The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle:Passcodes

Determine the format to use for the mapping information.

Configuration format (yml, xml, php, or annotation) [annotation]: php

Instead of starting with a blank entity, you can add some fields now.
Note that the primary key will be added automatically (named id).

Available types: array, simple_array, json_array, object, 
boolean, integer, smallint, bigint, string, text, datetime, datetimetz, 
date, time, decimal, float, binary, blob, guid.

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): site  
Field type [string]: 
Field length [255]: 
Is nullable [false]: true
Unique [false]: 

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): email
Field type [string]: 
Field length [255]: 
Is nullable [false]: true
Unique [false]: 

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): username
Field type [string]: 
Field length [255]: 
Is nullable [false]: true
Unique [false]: 

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): passcode
Field type [string]: 
Field length [255]: 
Is nullable [false]: true
Unique [false]: 

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): notes
Field type [string]: text
Is nullable [false]: true
Unique [false]: 

New field name (press <return> to stop adding fields): 

                     
  Entity generation  
                     

  created ./src/PasscodeBundle/Entity/
  created ./src/PasscodeBundle/Entity/Passcodes.php
  created ./src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/
  created ./src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Passcodes.orm.php
> Generating entity class src/PasscodeBundle/Entity/Passcodes.php: OK!
> Generating repository class src/PasscodeBundle/Repository/PasscodesRepository.php: OK!
> Generating mapping file src/PasscodeBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Passcodes.orm.php: OK!

                                         
  Everything is OK! Now get to work :).  
                                         

➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud                    

                                           
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 CRUD generator  
                                           


This command helps you generate CRUD controllers and templates.

First, give the name of the existing entity for which you want to generate a CRUD
(use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post)

The Entity shortcut name: 
➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud

                                           
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 CRUD generator  
                                           


This command helps you generate CRUD controllers and templates.

First, give the name of the existing entity for which you want to generate a CRUD
(use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post)

The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle:Passcodes

                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Entity "Passcodes" does not exist in the "PasscodeBundle" bundle. You may h  
  ave mistyped the bundle name or maybe the entity doesn't exist yet (create   
  it first with the "doctrine:generate:entity" command).                       
                                                                               

doctrine:generate:crud [--entity ENTITY] [--route-prefix ROUTE-PREFIX] [--with-write] [--format FORMAT] [--overwrite] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<entity>]

➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud

                                           
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 CRUD generator  
                                           


This command helps you generate CRUD controllers and templates.

First, give the name of the existing entity for which you want to generate a CRUD
(use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post)

The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle:
 The entity name isn't valid ("PasscodeBundle:" given, expecting something like AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post) 
The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle:Passcode

                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Entity "Passcode" does not exist in the "PasscodeBundle" bundle. You may ha  
  ve mistyped the bundle name or maybe the entity doesn't exist yet (create i  
  t first with the "doctrine:generate:entity" command).                        
                                                                               

doctrine:generate:crud [--entity ENTITY] [--route-prefix ROUTE-PREFIX] [--with-write] [--format FORMAT] [--overwrite] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<entity>]

➜  keys php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
No Metadata Classes to process.
➜  keys php bin/console doctrine:generate:form

                                                          
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Not enough arguments (missing: "entity").               
                                                          

doctrine:generate:form [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <entity>

➜  keys php bin/console doctrine:generate:form PasscodeBundle:Passcodes

                                                    
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                       
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'PasscodeBundle'.  
                                                    

doctrine:generate:form [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <entity>

➜  keys php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud                         

                                           
  Welcome to the Doctrine2 CRUD generator  
                                           


This command helps you generate CRUD controllers and templates.

First, give the name of the existing entity for which you want to generate a CRUD
(use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post)

The Entity shortcut name: PasscodeBundle:Passcodes

                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Entity "Passcodes" does not exist in the "PasscodeBundle" bundle. You may h  
  ave mistyped the bundle name or maybe the entity doesn't exist yet (create   
  it first with the "doctrine:generate:entity" command).                       
                                                                               

doctrine:generate:crud [--entity ENTITY] [--route-prefix ROUTE-PREFIX] [--with-write] [--format FORMAT] [--overwrite] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<entity>]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? As you can see above, I referenced and tried some things from [Symfony3 : Generate crud doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448122/symfony3-generate-crud-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue when using `php` for the Entity's configuration format in `bin/console doctrine:generate:entity`. Unfortunately just deleting the entity class and re-running the command is not enough. Since this seems to be a new project I recommend starting from scratch:

```
symfony new keys
```

Then update your settings, e.g. database settings in parameters.yml. You don't have to create a bundle as you can put everything into the default `AppBundle`.

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entity

> AppBundle:Passcode
```

Then choose `annotation` format and type all your field requirements as you did before.

Now you should be able to generate the crud:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:crud

> AppBundle:Passcode
```

<s>Here you can use whatever configuration format you like.</s> When you use AppBundle you have to use `yml` as that is the current format and the generator does not like mixing styles. If you have your own bundle you can use whatever configuration format you like.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. Up until the end where it threw:

Comment: [ERROR] The bundle's "Resources/config/routing.yml" file cannot be imported
from "app/config/routing.yml" because the "AppBundle" bundle is
already imported. Make sure you are not using two different
configuration/routing formats in the same bundle because it won't work.
OK

Comment: is that expected?

Comment: To be honest, I never really used the GeneratorBundle. I was suprised that it already didn't play well with entities using php-config. The error you report seems to be expected, because the existing AppBundle uses yml-configuration. So you might have to use yml as well or really create your own bundle like you originally wanted to.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!